# htaccess The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need help with Rewrite issues.

I believe this is the line causing the problem.

```
#define listing
RewriteRule ^([^/][\w\-\_]+)(.+)-l?([0-9]+).ht(m|ml)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&listing_id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

when I visit this page http://qvoo.no-ip.org/listings/clothing-and-shoes/children-s-clothes/cute-korea-cartoon-character-kids-adult-socks-make-1.html 
it shows me `The page isn't redirecting properly`

additional info

- PHP Version 5.5.15
- Apache 2.2

Full code

```
# enable apache morRewrite module #
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# set files headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|htc)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# deflate static content
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/x-component text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>

# allow request methods
 <Limit POST PUT DELETE GET OPTIONS HEAD>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from All
 </Limit>

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


 ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

 # define system languages
  RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.{2})?/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

 # define paging
  RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/index([0-9]*).ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&pg=$3 [QSA,L]

# define listing
RewriteRule ^([^/][\w\-\_]+)(.+)-l?([0-9]+).ht(m|ml)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2&listing_id=$3 [QSA,L]

 # define account details request
 RewriteRule ^((\w{2})/)?([\w-_]{3,})$ index.php?page=$3&lang=$2&account_request [QSA,L]

 # define single pages
  RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(^/*)?.ht(m?ml?)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

 # define other pages  
  RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/?(.*)?/?(.*)?(.ht(m?ml?)|/+)$ index.php?page=$1&rlVareables=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Just as a side note, the RewriteCond only works for the first next RewriteRule, so I don't understand putting it before an ErrorDocument

Comment: Thanks for your side note, any idea how to fix my issues?

Comment: The error you are getting means that a two or more rules are redirecting to each other (which causes an infinite loop), but I can't figure out which. What I would suggest you to do, is to check the rewrite logs of apache. You should also duplicate those RewriteCond you got and put it before each RewriteRule